# Git LFS track dynamic folders

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I am trying to configure a project, and it seems wherever we have textures, they seem to be very large for git. However, as we are working in unreal, these are labeled as .uasset files, along with every other asset. Also, not all textures will be in the same folder, as we want to separate textures associated to different models. To do this, I thought it would be quite simple to track files of the following type: `git lfs track "*/Textures/*.uasset"`

However, this doesn't seem to work, is git able to search dynamically like this, or do I have to explicitly imply the root folder, such as "Assets/Art/Dog/Textures/*.uasset"?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Try `git lfs track "**/Textures/*.uasset"`.  That is, two asterisks at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To search directories and down any sub directories, two *'s are needed as opposed to one. The correct pattern to match in this case would be `git lfs track "**/Textures/*.uasset"` If we wanted to track down sub-directories from the Textures directory, we would instead use `git lfs track "**/Textures/**.uasset"`